# Is it fine to ask "How do I improve this question" type of questions?

Tags: discussion

Is it fine to ask "How do I improve this question" type of questions on meta? These types of questions enhance the quality of StackExchange, but yet asking question like this can get redundant on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can ask such a question. Meta is full of such questions.  But you should ask in the comments of your question first.

Also, you should see if there is a similar question that may already answer your specific question.  (This can be a bit difficult if you don't know why your question needs to be improved).

If you do ask the question, and it has already been answered, your question may well be closed as a duplicate.